# how to draw an isothermal curve in pgf tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, arrow-curve

I am working on a thermodynamic course. I want to draw an isothermal curve in the diagram of clapeyron and try this with the code below:

[image: isothermal transformation]

I want to draw on the curve a colored surface between the point x = 3 and x = 6?

I want to add a arrow indicating the sense of direction of transformation from?

I'm using this code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{fleche/.style args={#1:#2}{ postaction = decorate,decoration={name=markings,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow[#2,scale=2]{>}}}}}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    xmin=0, xmax=10, 
    ymin=0, ymax=10,
    xlabel={Volume $(m^3)$},
    ylabel={Pression $Pa$},
    ytick=\empty,
   % extra y ticks={8},
    extra y tick style={align=center, font=\scriptsize},
    %extra y tick labels={normal\\health},
    extra y ticks={1.5,6},
    extra y tick labels={$\text{P}_\text{1}$,$\text{P}_\text{2}$},
    xtick=\empty,
    extra x ticks={3,6},
    extra x tick labels={$\text{V}_\text{1}$,$\text{V}_\text{2}$},
    ]
    \addplot[dashed, domain=0:3] {6};
    \addplot[dashed, domain=0:6] {1.5};

    \draw (axis cs:3,6) to [bend right=30]
        coordinate[pos=0] (B') coordinate[pos=0.17] (B) coordinate[pos=0.6] (B'') (axis cs:6,1.5);
     \addplot[color=red,fill=red, pattern=north east lines,  domain=3:6,samples=100] {6} \closedcycle;
     \addplot+[mark=none,domain=3:6,fill=blue!20!white] {axis cs:6,0;axis cs:3,6} \closedcycle;
    \draw[dashed, thin] (axis cs:6,1.5) -- (axis cs:6,0);
    \draw[dashed, thin] (axis cs:3,6) -- (axis cs:3,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the first question? Which surface?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  I also don't know what you exactly want to achieve.  Could you sketch on your diagram what you want to do and/or modify the text, please!?

Comment: i want to draw the geometrical surface between the axis x=V1 and x=V2, of this function, but, i don't have any expression P=f(V), so i use list of points `axis cs:6,1.5 ..`

i want to explain to my students the work can be considered like a surface , in the clapeyron diagram. for this raison i want to colorate the integrated surface of P=f(V) between V1 to V2

Comment: Please don't use `\text` like this, that command does not do what you think, and `_\text` is equally as bad even if it works in this case. Use mathrm or textup instead. This wrong use of `\text` is a **very** common error, and visitors should preferably not be encouraged to use it like this. Btw why `\text{1}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Revised answer (using PGFPlots v1.16)

With the release of the PGFPlots v1.16 it is now possible to use pgf declared constants/functions almost everywhere. With that it is now easy to draw the real P-V-curve as well as the corresponding axis ticklabels very easily.

For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        decorations.markings,
    }
    \tikzset{
        fleche/.style args={#1:#2}{
            postaction=decorate,
            decoration={
                name=markings,
                mark=at position #1 with {\arrow[#2,scale=2]{>}}
            },
        },
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher, so TikZ coordinates don't have to
        % be prefixed with `axis cs:'
        compat=1.11,
        % define some values and functions to "automatically" draw the
        % desired plot afterwards, regardless of the values
        % (only the values for `xmax' and `ymax' have to be adjusted accordingly)
        % ideal gas law: P V = n R T = const
        /pgf/declare function={
            % define V1, V2 and P1
            Vone = 3;
            Vtwo = 6;
            Pone = 6;
            % calculate constant nRT
            nRT = Vone * Pone;
            % now any P can be calculated for a given V
            P(\V) = nRT/\V;
            % for simplicity of later use already calc P2 here and assign the
            % result to a constant
            Ptwo = P(Vtwo);
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        xmin=0,xmax=10,
        ymin=0,ymax=10,
        % the ticks can be positioned at the declared constants "automatically"
        xtick={Vone,Vtwo},
        xticklabels={$V_1$,$V_2$},
        ytick={0,Ptwo,Pone},
        yticklabels={0,$P_2$,$P_1$},
        axis on top,
    ]

        % fill the area below the curve
        % (draw it first, so it is below everything else)
        \addplot [
            draw=none,
            fill=red!40,
            % the declared constants can also be used here
            domain=Vone:Vtwo,
        ] {P(x)}
            \closedcycle
        ;

        % now draw the curve with the arrow on the line
        \addplot [
            thick,
            domain=Vone:Vtwo,
            fleche={0.6:red},
        ] {P(x)}
            coordinate [pos=0] (start)
            coordinate [pos=1] (end)
        ;

        % draw dashed lines and start and end points
        % (and here the declared constants can be used as well)
        \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \point in {start,end} {
            \edef\temp{
                \noexpand\draw [dashed]
                    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0 |- \point) --
                    (\point) circle (2pt) --
                    (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin} -| \point);
                \noexpand\fill (\point) circle (2pt);
            }\temp
        }

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

### Original answer (using PGFPlots v1.15)

I edited my answer after you have shown in [your answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410864/95441) what you really wanted the plot look like. For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        decorations.markings,       % <-- missed to load
    }
    \tikzset{
        fleche/.style args={#1:#2}{
            postaction=decorate,
            decoration={
                name=markings,
                mark=at position #1 with {\arrow[#2,scale=2]{>}}
            },
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        xmin=0, xmax=10,
        ymin=0, ymax=10,
%        % (made labels more common)
%        % (because of the "sketch" type of the plot these should not be needed)
%        xlabel={Volume $(\mathrm{m}^3)$},
%        ylabel={Pressure (Pa)},
        % (changed ticks + labels to normal ticks instead of extra ticks)
        xtick={3,6},
        xticklabels={$V_1$,$V_2$},
        ytick={1.5,6},
        yticklabels={$P_2$,$P_1$},  % <-- (changed order of entries)
    ]
        % fill the area below the curve
        % (draw it first, so it is below everything else)
        \fill [
            red!40,
        ]
            (axis cs:3,6) to [bend right=30]
            (axis cs:6,1.5) |-
            (axis cs:3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) --
            cycle
        ;

        % draw the dashed lines
        % (using two different approaches)
        \addplot [dashed,domain=0:3,samples=2] {6};
        \addplot [dashed,domain=0:6,samples=2] {1.5};

        \draw [dashed,thin] (axis cs:6,1.5) -- (axis cs:6,0);
        \draw [dashed,thin] (axis cs:3,6)   -- (axis cs:3,0);

        % now draw the curve
        \draw [
            fleche={0.6:red},
            thick,              % <-- added
        ] (axis cs:3,6) to [bend right=30]
            % store start and end coordinates
            coordinate [pos=0] (start)
            coordinate [pos=1] (end)
        (axis cs:6,1.5);

        % draw start and end point
        \fill [radius=2pt]
            (start) circle[]
            (end)   circle[];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 1):

p V = n k T = const

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        decorations.markings,       
        patterns,
    }
    \tikzset{
        fleche/.style args={#1:#2}{
            postaction=decorate,
            decoration={
                name=markings,
                mark=at position #1 with {\arrow[#2,scale=2]{>}}
            },
        },
    }
\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{fleche/.style args={#1:#2}{ postaction = decorate,decoration={name=markings,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow[#2,scale=2]{>}}}}}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    xmin=0, xmax=10, 
    ymin=0, ymax=10,
    xlabel={Volume $(m^3)$},
    ylabel={Pression $Pa$},
    ytick=\empty,
   % extra y ticks={8},
    extra y tick style={align=center, font=\scriptsize},
    %extra y tick labels={normal\\health},
    extra y ticks={1.5,6},
    extra y tick labels={$P_1$,$P_2$},
    xtick=\empty,
    extra x ticks={3,6},
    extra x tick labels={$V_1$,$V_2$},
    ]
    \addplot[dashed, domain=0:3] {6};
    \addplot[dashed, domain=0:6] {1.5};

%     \draw (axis cs:3,6) to [bend right=30]
%         coordinate[pos=0] (B') coordinate[pos=0.17] (B) coordinate[pos=0.6] (B'') (axis cs:6,1.5);
    \addplot [domain=3:6,fill=red, pattern=north east lines] (\x,{6/(\x-2)})\closedcycle;
    \draw[dashed, thin] (axis cs:6,1.5) -- (axis cs:6,0);
    \draw[dashed, thin] (axis cs:3,6) -- (axis cs:3,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your quick reply, by two this answers i can draw my figure

Comment: Btw: please don't use the `\text ` command like that. I know the op did and I'll comment there as well. Otherwise +1 for a good answer

Comment: @daleif Done. I did not pay any attention to this. The only purpose of this post was that one does not have to guess the curve, nor fake it, but just open a random book on thermodynamics.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you, I got to that I want

[image]

by modifying the first code

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        decorations.markings,       % <-- missed to load
        patterns,
    }
    \tikzset{
        fleche/.style args={#1:#2}{
            postaction=decorate,
            decoration={
                name=markings,
                mark=at position #1 with {\arrow[#2,scale=2]{>}}
            },
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        xmin=0, xmax=10,
        ymin=0, ymax=10,
%        % (made labels more common)
%        % (because of the "sketch" type of the plot these should not be needed)
%        xlabel={Volume $(\mathrm{m}^3)$},
%        ylabel={Pressure (Pa)},
        % (changed ticks + labels to normal ticks instead of extra ticks)
        xtick={3,6},
        xticklabels={$V_1$,$V_2$},
        ytick={1.5,6},
        yticklabels={$P_2$,$P_1$},  % <-- (changed order of entries)
    ]
        % fill the area below the curve
        % (draw it first, so it is below everything else)
        \fill [
            red!40,
        ]
            (axis cs:3,6) to [bend right=30]
            (axis cs:6,1.5) |-
            (axis cs:3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) --
            cycle
        ;

        \addplot [dashed, domain=0:3] {6};
        \addplot [dashed, domain=0:6] {1.5};

        \draw [
            fleche={0.6:red},
            thick,              % <-- added
        ] (axis cs:3,6) to [bend right=30]
        (axis cs:6,1.5);
         \node[coordinate, pin=+30:{W=surface}, anchor=center,fill=red,circle,scale=0.3]at (axis cs:4.0,2.3){};
        \draw [dashed, thin] (axis cs:6,1.5) -- (axis cs:6,0);
        \draw [dashed, thin] (axis cs:3,6)   -- (axis cs:3,0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of writing your own answer which is basically the same as mine (except for the superfluous stuff that was unclear in your question), please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).